# How to determine MRF24WG0MA wifi bottleneck?

Tags: wifi

I have a PIC32 running a MRF24WG0MA (which is a b/g wifi transceiver which supports up to 11MBaud on b and 54Mbaud on g).

I have measured the sustained transmission thruput over several minutes at approximately 800 KBaud.  I was hoping to get several MBaud.

I get MBaud speed from a laptop on the wifi network so I don't think it is an infrastructure problem.
I think it is either the PIC32 or the MRF24 chipset.

What is the best way to determine where the bottleneck is?

Currently my approach is to first analyze the packet timing with WireShark, then dive into the TCP/IP Stack provided my Microchip.

Comment: Are you running this as a client or server?  Infrastructure or ad-hoc?  Encrypted or open?

Comment: The MRF24 is running as on an infrastructure network with WPA2 encryption as server on 2 ports: 80 (HTTP) and 8760 (Generic TCP server).  I measured the thruput in adhoc mode with WEP, didn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try tweaking the SPI up to 20M instead of the default 10M (WF_MAX_SPI_FREQ).  Setting the optimization to 3 helps too.  Also make sure you try the latest libraries.

Are you using iperf to measure the throughput or just monitoring file transfers?  iperf will give you more consistent test results.

Comment: Good idea on the SPI, the max speed that the MRF can run is 25 MHZ.The client calculates thruput after every 100K bytes received. I will check out iperf.